# Gwibber error with facebook log in-with strange warning

Tags: gwibber, facebook

Gwibber used to work fine. Then after resetting my accounts it wont log in and gives this error in red but refuses log in

Success 
SECURITY WARNING: The above URL is NOT NOT VALID FOR A CASH CARD OR GIFT CARD. Giving away the URL may result in your account being HIJACKED.

Comment: It looks as if it may be a security exploit. I'd file a bug as a security vulnerability (embargoed) and give whaever details you can.

Answer (score 3):

Related bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gwibber/+bug/1058672
I dont think is an exploit, maybe something has changed on Facebook.